# Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-physics, skspritenode

I am creating a game and i keep getting this error for my bullet spawn method linked with a joystick. I want to repetitively spawn nodes when the joystick is active Here is how i am creating a firing method

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

if fireWeapon == true {

 NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.25, target: self, 
 selector: Selector ("spawnBullet1"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
 }
}
func spawnBullet1(){

self.addChild(bullet1)

bullet1.position = CGPoint (x: hero.position.x , y:hero.position.y) 
bullet1.xScale = 0.5
bullet1.yScale = 0.5
bullet1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bullet1.size)
bullet1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bullet1
bullet1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.enemy1
bullet1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
bullet1.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
}
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent  
event:UIEvent?) {

for touch in touches {
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

    let node = nodeAtPoint(location)
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(joystick.frame, location)) {
        stickActive = true

        if stickActive == true {

        fireWeapon = true
}
```

the first bullet launches as planned and works great however, every time the second bullet launches the app crashes and i get the error. can someone tell me an alternative way to create a fire rate

Comment: You need to remove bullet1 before firing the next bullet, or create new bullet each time.

Comment: Show us where the variable bullet1 is created

Comment: what do you mean when you say created @MateHegedus

Comment: Where is the variable bullet1 declared??

Comment: in the NSTimer method @mateHegedus i have also tried a run block method that did not work

Comment: Dude I can't help you if you don't tell me where/how bullet1 is declared. It looks something like: var bullet1 = ...

Comment: ohhhhhh i see what you're saying @MateHege     let bullet1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet.png") in my class before my override view method

Comment: Yes. So something like self.addChild(SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet.png"))

Comment: but if i  declare bullet1 in my spawn bullet method how do i call bullet1 one in other methods @MateHegedus i have it defined in my class so i can call it in other methods because i have bullet1 move in the direction of a joystick

Comment: Then do let bullet1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet.png")

Comment: i already am for my class. Can you update your answer? i don't understand @MateHegedus

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110553/discussion-between-gkolman-and-mate-hegedus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `self.addChild(bullet1)` you need something like `self.addChild(SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet.png"))`

This because you need to create a new bullet every time you fire, you do not want to move the same bullet every single time.

Comment: so you're saying i need to create a separate method  called createbullet () which adds the child and then call that method in my spawnBullet1 () method @mateHegedus

Comment: @gkolman no, you need something like self.addChild(createBullet())

Comment: what do you mean createBullet()? why would a variable contain input parameters, is that a variable or a method?

Comment: so you want me to create a separate function with self.addchild(bullet1) in it then call that method in my spawnbullet1() method? @MateHegedus